# Javascript regex match only characters

Tags: javascript, regex

From a string I need to pull out any word beginning with dog. Eg. "dog", "doggy", "doggystyle".

Howto?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What errors or unexpected output are you getting?

Comment: I hit enter to soon! I had'nt finished my question and now I can't seem to delete it?

Comment: @adp, because I already added an answer, but you can still edit your answer and complete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `/(\bdog\w*)/g`, e.g.

```
"dog dogman doggy notdoggy doggyagain".match(/(\bdog\w*)/g)
// => ["dog", "dogman", "doggy", "doggyagain"]
```

The `/g` flag is important. It makes the regex match all occurences, not only the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
\bdog\w*
```

`\b` is a word boundary

`\w` is a word character

`*` means 0 or more

Comment: that won't match dog, it'll only match doggy etc.  you'd need to use * for zero or more instead.

Answer (score 0):

Trivally, you could use the `split()` function combined with the `substr()` function to do this as well.  e.g.

```
var str = "dog doggy other doggystyle";

// Split string by spaces.
var result = str.split(" ");  // Split on the space character.

// Iterate through array, split on space.
for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++){

   // Identify words that start with "dog"
   if(result[i].substr(0, 3) == "dog")
   {
      // Word starts with dog.  Do something with it here.
   }
}
```

Comment: you can use matches() method available in String class like this, str.matches("^dog{1}*$"). However the questioner is asking how to do in javascript.